# How do I include jquery validation in an MVC Ajax form correctly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an Ajax form in my MVC application that is validated using jquery validation.  Initially the validation wasn't working because the date fields where in a UK format instead of US (which is by design as I'm UK based), so I added some code to stop that.

**Jquery Validation Date**

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("date", function(value, element) {
        var dateReg = /^\d{2}([./-])\d{2}\1\d{4}$/;
        return value.match(dateReg);
    }, "Invalid date");

    $('#form').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

The code I added however hijacks the form.submit which means the ajax form doesn't trigger it's **success** or **failure** functions.

**Ajax Form Code**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Fixtures", new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "Success",
    OnFailure = "Failure"    
}, new { @class = "standard-form", @Id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    ...Form fields etc...
}
```

**Script**

```
function Success() {
    console.log("Success")
}
 function Failure() {
    console.log("Failure")
}
```

The whole way this is doesn't doens't feel clean to me, so my question is how do I validate the form correctly (using jquery validate or an alternative) but also **retain** the success and failure functions of my ajax form?

Comment: How about using `DataAnnotations` to validate your model or view model and combine that with jQuery unobtusive validation?

Comment: Your regex is not validating a date. If you want to allow for a `dd/MM/yyyy` format, then you can look at using [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) or if your using a jquery datepicker, then use its methods (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for jQuery-ui datepicker).

Comment: Alternatively you could use the script in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594128/error-in-date-validation-mvc/30609111#30609111)

Comment: And note you also need to remove the `$('#form').validate({... });` script - that does not work with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.jds`

Comment: Why don't you set the date format for jQuery to UK format instead?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, in the end and after a little digging through some of the documentation you guys mentioned I found that you can set dateITA to true.  Here is the code for this.

```
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            dateITA: true
        }
    })
```

This approach works very well for my application and means I can retain all my Ajax form options without any problems. Since I only ever have one form in my views there was no need to worry about the use of conflicting ids.