# ASP MVC 5 Date Format Validation Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP MVC 5 web application, I need to display a date in a specific format. When the page loads, the text is formatted correctly. But if you edit the value or simply try to post, the validation error is shown:

[image]

The field is defined like this:

```
        @*Creation*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Creation, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Creation, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Creation)
        </div>
    </div>
```

The viewmodel property is defined as:

```
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Creation", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
```

The screenshot was created using Firefox browser. If I do the same on Edge, the validation passes, but the biding of this property on the post method is invalid (a default date value).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: As Matt Spinks has noted, this a `jquery.validate.js` issue (which validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy`) and you need to override the validator (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594128/error-in-date-validation-mvc/30609111#30609111) for more detail.

Comment: The reason it works in Edge (and in Chrome) is because you have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` which generates `type="date"` which means the browsers implementation of a DatePicker will be displayed, but to make that work correctly you need to use `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format)

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677035/date-of-birth-validation-keeps-showing/39682410#39682410) which includes a script you can include in your view for client side validation.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that, behind the scenes, the validation is actually being performed by jQuery. So the key is to tell the **jQuery validator** that you will be using the *dd/MM/yyyy* format.

There are a couple ways of doing this. The simplest way is to just override the validator function (for dates) with a simpe tweak:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.validator.addMethod('date',
    function (value, element) {
      $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-AU");
      var date = Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-AU");
      return this.optional(element) || 
        !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date).toString());
    });
});
```

An alternative would be to use a globalization library for jQuery. There is a globalization library that you can use [here](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize).

When you have the library, include these files:

```
globalize.js 
globalize.culture.en-AU.js
```

Then override the validator function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            Globalize.culture("en-AU"); // the UK format
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value) !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, I installed the library (via NuGet package), did NOT manually add any files and then override validation function. My location is pt-BR so I replaced "en-AU" to "pt". Now the validation does not get anything. If I type a erroneous date like: 30/12/2016dssfds it does not validate. Besides, the binding is still failing. Any ideas?

Comment: You might check to make sure all your files are being included correctly (no 404's).

Comment: I tried also the simplest way you suggested (simple tweak) and the result is exactly the same. No validation takes places. I removed the globalize package to make sure it does not influence the tweak. What do you mean by checking for 404´s?

Comment: Back to the globalize package approach, I also tried to include globalize.js and globalize.culture.pt.js files in the BundleConfig.cs. But this did not influence the result.

Comment: Thank you Matt you saved my day was getting very frustrated with my "blind date" (Razor, Boostrap, jQuery)