# Override validator function for dates (ASP MVC 5)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to override the validator function for a date field defined as:

```
@*Creation*@
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Creation, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Creation, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Creation)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Accordingly to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010704/asp-mvc-5-date-format-validation-issue), this should be a simple solution to fix my date format issue, but when I try to do the suggested approach, no validation happens at all.

Due to my lack of experience in ASP MVC and jquery, I might be missing something simple. I added this override on the same view (cshtml) of the form, under the Scripts Section:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            $.culture = Globalize.culture("pt-BR");
            var date = Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "pt-BR");
            return this.optional(element) ||
              !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date).toString());
        });
    });
</script>
});
```

No validation happens when the script is there. If I remove the script, the validation does not respect the date format.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Don't put it inside `jQuery(function ($) {`

Comment: I don´t understand you comment, @StephenMuecke

Comment: Just delete the `jQuery(function ($) {` line of code (and its closing `});`)