# Date dd/MM/yyyy isn't being populated in input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I'm working in an MVC application. I would like my date to be always in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` for example `16/04/2017`.

Here's a scenario from my application. I have a `SaleOrder.cs` entity, I have a `public DateTime Date { get; set; }` property. When **viewing the details** of the SaleOrder, I'd like the date to show as `16 Apr 2017` and when editing a SaleOrder, I'd like the input to be populated in the following format `16/04/2017`.

This isn't happening for me at the moment. I've captured the current behaviour in the [following screencast](https://www.screencast.com/t/BqMGBoqwa).

My EditorTemplate for `DateTime` is like so:

```
@model DateTime
@{
  IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes;
  object objAttributes;
  if (ViewData.TryGetValue("htmlAttributes", out objAttributes))
  {
    htmlAttributes = objAttributes as IDictionary<string, object> ?? HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(objAttributes);
  }
  else
  {
    htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();
  }
  htmlAttributes.Add("type", "date");
  var format = (Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome")) ? "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" : "{0:d}";
  @Html.TextBox("", Model, format, htmlAttributes)
}
```

How can I get my DateTime values to behave?

Comment: Are you _really_ sure your `(Request.UserAgent != null && Request.UserAgent.Contains("Chrome"))` does not returns `false`?

Comment: Yep, I debugged and that is `true`

Comment: Seems that `DisplayTemplates` and `EditorTemplates` are suitable way to handle different formatting `DateTime` properties in your issue. Which kind of unobtrusive data validation apply (using `data-val-*` attribute or `jquery.validate`)?

Comment: You do not need to create an `EditorTemplate` for this. Just use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")` or if you want the HTML-5 datepicker, then you need to use ISO format -
 `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { type = "date" })` (note you also need to reconfigure the `$.validator` is you using client side validation)

Comment: @StephenMuecke reconfigure the validator how? Can you please provide further info? :)

Comment: I don't think my question is a duplicate, they're using jQuery UI, and I'm not using any such thing. I believe WebKit browsers (e.g. Chrome) give me the picker for free.

Comment: Depends on if you using the HTML-5 date picker, or a jquery datepicker or a plain textbox for entering a date - refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594128/error-in-date-validation-mvc/30609111#30609111)

Comment: And it is an exact duplicate - that question and the answer relate to the HTML-5 datepicker which you video shows your using (and note that its only supported in Chrome and Edge and it will display a standard textbox in FireFox and IE etc)

Comment: my bad @StephenMuecke, I just noticed he began the question with jquery and jquery UI. Does it matter that he's using a `string` for the date? Mine is a `DateTime` proeprty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141866/discussion-between-ciwan-and-stephen-muecke).