# Which Data Annotation attribute creates this validation attribute?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

Presuming we have a model like so:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    public string DateTime? Image_Date { get; set; }
}
```

And it is added to a Razor view like so:

```
Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image_Date)
```

Then the following is rendered in the browser:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Image_Date must be a date." id="Image_Date" name="Image_Date" type="text" value="" />
```

The attribute `data-val-date` is what I'm interested in. It's plainly being injected in by MVC's "unobtrusive" jQuery validation integration.

#### So, what data annotation will override the verbiage in the HTML attribute?

For instance, `[Required(ErrorMessage="This field is required!")]` will override the standard "The field {0} is required." message.

---

Failed attempts:

1. `[DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid date.")]` doesn't appear to do anything to client-side validation.
2. `[DisplayName("...")]` changes the wildcard portion of the pattern, but obviously doesn't affect the pattern itself.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to fix it manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510221/how-to-fix-the-field-must-be-a-date-on-a-datetime-property-in-mvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data-val-date` attribute is added by the framework because the property is type of `DateTime?`. Its the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of the `HtmlHelper` class which actually generates all the `data-val-*` attributes.

Note that `[DataType(DataType.Date, "...")]` is an attribute used by the `EditorFor()` method to add the `type="date"` attribute which in turn generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (if its supported by the browser) and is not related with client side validation.

The default error messages are defined in Resource files, and you can create you own to override the defaults.

Create a (say) `MyResources.resx` in the `App_GlobalResources` folder (you may need to create this folder) and add the following `FieldMustBeDate` key and your message (the default message is shown below)

```
FieldMustBeDate : The field {0} must be a date
```

and add the following in the `Application_Start()` of `Global.asax`

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";
```

Note you can also override the default error message for the `[Required]` attribute using the `PropertyValueRequired` key

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this answered since this appears to be correct, but can you show how you found `FieldMustBeDate`?

Comment: Its defined in the [MvcResources.resx](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Properties/MvcResources.resx) (line 445) and accessed via [ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.cs). (line 97) ASAIK, their are 4 defaults you can override - `FieldMustBeDate`, `FieldMustBeNumeric`, `PropertyValueInvalid` and `PropertyValueRequired`

Comment: I've had no joy getting the default required message overriden. Are you certain about `PropertyValueRequired`?

Comment: @Kivin, Almost certain, but I think your need an additional setting in your `Global.asax` - `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources";` because `PropertyValueInvalid` and `PropertyValueRequired` are defined in a different namespace (`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`). I'm on leave at the moment so cant confirm at the moment, but found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc) with a bit more info