# Kentico - Not able to save the DateTime in "DD/MM/YYYY" format

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

I am working on Kentico 12 MVC Site in version 12.0.59 and default culture set to "en-AU".

I have created a Form named "Sample Form".

When I am trying to save the datetime in either "MM/DD/YYYY" or "YYYY/MM/DD" it works correctly and saves the data in the database for the form.

But when I try to save the datetime in format "DD/MM/YYYY" and click on Submit button to save the data in database, it shows the error as follows:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason for that is a missing culture setting for the current thread in the code. It is not enough just to select the default culture "en-AU" in the Kentico admin interface. In the code before processing your request you should set the desired culture for the thread as well:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = yourDefaultOrSelectedCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = yourDefaultOrSelectedCulture;
```

In Kentico example Dancing Goat MVC website you can see this implemented in **MultiCultureMvcRouteHandler.cs** code file.