# ASP.NET MVC Binding Nested List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the solution suggested in Mel's space (https://mleeb.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/editing-nested-lists-in-asp-mvc-4/) 
for editing nested list

Basically I have my model as below

```
ProductEditModel

 --> ProductAudioEditModel

    --> ProductAssetResourceEditModel
```

I got this working for the below

```
 @Html.EditorFor(c => resource.TrackTitle, null, Html.GetHtmlName("TrackTitle"))
```

which gives me the correct value when it's edited.

However, I couldnt get this working for DropDownList or I am not able to pick the edited value in the dropdownlist . It always give me the original value in my controller.

```
 @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ProductAssetAudios", out parentIdentifier))
  {
       .....
        @foreach (var resource in Model.ProductAssetResources.OrderBy(a => a.ResourceNumber))
          {
            string childIdentifier = null; 
             @using (Html.BeginChildCollectionItem("ProductAssetResources", parentIdentifier, out childIdentifier))
              {
                  @Html.HiddenFor(model => resource.AssetResourceStatusId, new { Name = Html.GetHtmlName(childIdentifier, "AssetResourceStatusId") })
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => resource.AssetResourceStatusId, new SelectList(visibleResourceStatuses, "AssetResourceStatusId", "Name", resource.AssetResourceStatusId),  new { @class = "inherit-title" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => resource.AssetResourceStatusId)

              }
          }
  }
```

The AssetResourceStatusId always holding the original value even though the drop down list is selected for a different value.

I was hoping that the EditorFor and DropDownListFor should be work in the same manner when editing  nested list.

### Edited

Generated HTML

### DropDownListFor

```
    <select class="inherit-title valid" id="ProductAssetAudios_0df86a5c-0a32-4b0f-97ee-3b3254f743d9__ProductAssetResources_c58ba43c-6081-41d4-88fd-d59799c7374e__resource_AssetResourceStatusId" name="ProductAssetAudios[0df86a5c-0a32-4b0f-97ee-3b3254f743d9].ProductAssetResources[c58ba43c-6081-41d4-88fd-d59799c7374e].resource.AssetResourceStatusId" aria-invalid="false"><option value="3">Extra</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Found</option>
    <option value="8">Ignore</option>
    </select>
```

### HiddenFor

```
<input name="ProductAssetAudios[b5670a6a-7a1d-4c76-86bc-85a05cd144c1].ProductAssetResources[aa378d38-0fb7-4304-9f24-79d0efcb36b9].AssetResourceStatusId" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AssetResourceStatusId must be a number." data-val-required="The AssetResourceStatusId field is required." id="ProductAssetAudios_b5670a6a-7a1d-4c76-86bc-85a05cd144c1__ProductAssetResources_aa378d38-0fb7-4304-9f24-79d0efcb36b9__resource_AssetResourceStatusId" type="hidden" value="2">
```

-Alan-

Comment: Show the actual html generated by both the `HiddenFor()` and `DropDownListFor()` methods.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have edited my question to include the generated HTMLs

Comment: Use a `for-loop` to generate the html and it should work

Comment: The hidden input is creating the correct `name` attribute assuming `ProductEditModel` contains a property `IEnumerable<ProductAudioEditModel> ProductAssetAudios` and `ProductAudioEditModel` contains a property `IEnumerable<ProductAssetResourceEditModel> ProductAssetAudios`. You need to generate the dropdownlist the same way as you currently generate the hidden input and then delete the hidden input

Comment: I also assume your are dynamically add new items to the nested collection in the view, otherwise you should not be using this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, your suggestion works very well. Can you answer this question , so that I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, what would be your suggestion if I dont intend to dynamically add new items to the collection in view but just updating the existing items?

Comment: @AlanB, If your not dynamically adding and deleting items in the view, then just use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). Will add an answer in an hour or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You model contains a collection property named `ProductAssetAudios` (typeof `ProductAudioEditModel`) and each object in that collection contains a collection property named `ProductAssetResources` (typeof `ProductAssetResourceEditModel`) and each of those objects contains a property named `AssetResourceStatusId`.

In C# code, if you were to get the `AssetResourceStatusId` value of the 1st `ProductAssetResourceEditModel` in the 1st `ProductAudioEditModel`, your code would be

```
var id = model.ProductAssetAudios[0].ProductAssetResources[0].AssetResourceStatusId;
```

Drop the `model` prefix and that is exactly how the `name` attribute of the control must be. What the `BeginCollectionItem()` and `BeginChildCollectionItem()` methods do is to modify the collection indexers to a `Guid` and adds a hidden input for the indexer to allow you to dynamically add and remove items from the collection. By default, the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind collections with zero-based consecutive indexers, unless a value for the indexers is also posted (i.e the reason why the hidden input is added).

In your case, the `name` attribute for the hidden input is correct, i.e. using

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => resource.AssetResourceStatusId, new { Name = Html.GetHtmlName(childIdentifier, "AssetResourceStatusId") })
```

because your overriding the default `name` attribute generated by `HiddenFor()`. You just need to do the same for the `DropDownListFor()` method, i.e. set the name attribute using `new { Name = Html.GetHtmlName(childIdentifier, "AssetResourceStatusId") }`. But then you also need to then delete the hidden input because the `DefaultModelBinder` will only bind the first value that is posted for a property. Note also that you will need to change the `ValidationMessageFor()` also.

---

Side note. From the comments it appears that you are not wanting to add and remove items in the view, in which case, do not use the `BeginCollectionItem()` and `BeginChildCollectionItem()` methods. Instead, just use nested `for` loops or custom `EditorTemplates` for typeof `ProductAudioEditModel` and `ProductAssetResourceEditModel`. An example of using `for` loops would be

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.ProductAssetAudios.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProductAssetAudios[i].SomeProperty)
    ....
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.ProductAssetAudios[i].ProductAssetResources.Count; j++)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductAssetAudios[i].ProductAssetResources[j].AssetResourceStatusId, new SelectList(.....)
```

Refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949050/list-of-objects-not-binding-to-the-model-on-post-back-in-asp-net-mvc-4/28954058#28954058) for an example of using a nested `EditorTemplate`.